# How to extract drainage network through gdaldem

Tags: flow, gdaldem

From gdaldem I can view slope, aspect, and hillshade maps.

```
"gdaldem slope manj.tif ouoi.tif -p -s 60"
"gdaldem aspect manj.tif gg.tif"
"gdaldem hillshade manj.tif hh.tif"
```

Is there any command to get flow direction map from gdaldem?

Can you give a working example of flow direction and drainage network extraction?

Comment: I have seen a link to RiverlifeGIS software that is free (not open source). You may want to try it. Download: http://toolbox.watersketch.net/userFiles/File/rlgissetup.zip some information http://www.wise-rtd.info/en/info/riverlifegis.

Answer (score 5):

I don't believe that GDAL currently offers the functionality needed to perform flow path modelling and automated stream network extraction. There are however many good open-source GIS alternatives that can be used for this task. I know that GRASS, SAGA, and QGIS each have tools for flow accumulation and stream network extraction. Also, I develop a free and open-source GIS called Whitebox Geospatial Analysis tools (can be downloaded [here](http://uoguelph.ca/~hydrogeo/Whitebox)) that has extensive tools for extracting flow direction, accumulation and stream networks. It includes several common flow algorithms (D8, FD8, D-infinity, FD-infinity) as well as tools for stream network analysis and hydrological analysis.

[image]

Comment: I am new to GRASS and QGIS provide any material related to .I didn't get from whitebox geospatial analysis tool

Comment: @user28536, Please see my reply to the question that you posted earlier.

Comment: In GRASS GIS there is no command for drainage line extraction?

Comment: GRASS GIS is doing this from its own cmd prompt .How can i get flow direction from my ms-dos cmd prompt

Comment: @user28536 I'm afraid that I cannot help you with GRASS specific instructions. Perhaps markusN would be better suited to that. I did however give you detailed instructions on how to extract a drainage network here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/113634/how-to-extract-drainage-line-network-from-grass-gis-and-qgis/113645#113645